# How can I open a Generic Inquiry onto another window in Acumatica?

Tags: acumatica

I have modified the DAC on the Sales Order screen to generate a BackOrder generic inquiry which is currently working. I however wanted to know if there was a way to open that GI onto another window instead of replacing the current screen I am on currently?

Below is the code I used to create the link to the GI

```
    public PXAction<SOOrder> ShowBackOrder; 
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Show Back Orders")] 
    [PXButton] 
    protected virtual void showBackOrder() 
    { 
      SOOrder current = Base.Document.Current;
      if (current.OrderNbr!= null)
      {
          string sURL = String.Format( "~/GenericInquiry/GenericInquiry.aspx?Name=BackOrders&Customer={0}", current.CustomerID); 
          throw new PXRedirectToUrlException(sURL, null);
      }

    } 

    public override void Initialize()
    {
        Base.report.AddMenuAction(ShowBackOrder);
    }

    protected void SOOrder_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        ShowBackOrder.SetEnabled(e.Row != null);
    }
```

I am thinking the answer may lie in the "PXRedirectToURLException" which is currently set to null. But I haven't been able to find anywhere what else could be entered in this field. I know that any external website is automatically opened in another window with the value of the second parameter still being null.

Hence, is there something I can enter to make my Generic Inquiry appear on a new window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw an overloaded format of the PXRedirectToUrlException as below

> public PXRedirectToUrlException(string url,
>   PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode newWindow, string message);

so you may try this

```
throw new PXRedirectToUrlException(sURL ,PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.New,null)
```